# Create new xml using python

Tags: python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

doc    = ET.parse("users.xml")
root = doc.getroot() #Returns the root element for this tree.
root.keys()          #Returns the elements attribute names as a list. The names are returned in an arbitrary order
for child in root:
    username             = child.attrib['username']
    password             = child.attrib['password']
    grant_admin_rights   = child.attrib['grant_admin_rights']
    create_private_share = child.attrib['create_private_share']
    uid                  = child.attrib['uid']



root  = ET.Element("users")
user  = ET.SubElement(root, "user")
user.set("username",username)
user.set("password",password)
user.set("grant_admin_rights",grant_admin_rights)
user.set("create_private_share",create_private_share)
user.set("uid",uid)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
myxml = tree.write("new.xml")
```

output of this code :-

```
<users><user create_private_share="no" grant_admin_rights="no" password="sp" uid
="1000" username="us" /></users>
```

But am trying to make it like this :-

```
<users>

<user create_private_share="no" grant_admin_rights="no" password="sp" uid
="1000" username="us" ><group>hfhfhf</group> </user>

</users>
```

instead of this `<user />`, am trying `<user> <group>fgfg</group>  </user>` . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`SubElement`](http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-elementtree-ElementTree.htm#elementtree.ElementTree.SubElement-function) factory function:

```
group = SubElement(user, "group")
# ...
```